# How to get the latest date when the game is played in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am making an quiz app with Swift and I have been struggling to display the day when the game is played. I am trying to get the data in checkGameEnded by using insert() but I have not succeeded yet (playerScore can be displayed without any problem). That would be really appreciated if you could give me an assistance. Thank you.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class PlayerItem {
    
    var playerScore : Int
    var date: Date
    
    init(playerScore: Int, date: Date) {
        self.playerScore = playerScore
        self.date = date
    }
}
View1
struct PlayGameView: View {
    
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct PlayGameView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    @State private var playerScore : Int = 0
    @State private var date: Date = .now
    @State private var buttonClicked = false
    @State private var idOfword = 0
    @State private var showTrueOrFalse = "Choose your answer!"
    @State private var isGameEnded = false
    @State var backtoTitle = false
    @State var firstChoice = "午後"
    @State var secondChoice = "午前"
    @State var numberOfLeftWords = 30
    @State var usedMoves: [Int] = []
    @State var mistakenMoves: [Int] = []
    
    let maxNumQuestion = 30
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                // set the brown wallpaper
                Image("image1")
                    // make the wallpaper a little lighter
                    .opacity(0.9)
                Spacer()
                VStack{
                    // display the remaining number of words
                    Text("\(String(numberOfLeftWords)) words left")
                        .frame(maxWidth:350, alignment: .leading)
                        .bold()
                        .padding(.top, 200)
                        .padding(.bottom, 50)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    Spacer()
                    // display the word for the question
                    Text(displayeWord[idOfword].word)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 100)
                        .background(.white)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30.0))
                        .padding(.bottom, 90)
                    Spacer()
                    // display "choose your answer" / ⚪︎ / ×
                        Text(showTrueOrFalse)
                            .bold()
                            .frame(height: 5)
                    // condition ? expressionIfTrue : expressionIfFalse
                            .font(showTrueOrFalse == "Choose your answer!" ? .system(size: 30): .system(size: 80))
                    // condition ? expressionIfTrue : expressionIfFalse
                            .foregroundColor(showTrueOrFalse == "Choose your answer!" ? .white : Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, opacity: 1.0))
                    Spacer()
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Button(firstChoice) {
    
                            // check if the answer is correct or not
                            checkAnswer(answer : firstChoice)
                            // prevent the double click
                            buttonClicked = true
                        }
                        .disabled(buttonClicked)
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 80)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title)
                        .background(.white)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40.0))
                        .padding(15)
                     
                        Button(secondChoice) {
                            // check if the answer is correct or not
                            checkAnswer(answer : secondChoice)
                            // prevent the double click
                            buttonClicked = true
                        }
                        .disabled(buttonClicked)
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 80)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title)
                        .background(.white)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40.0))
                        .padding(15)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .padding(.top,60)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Points")
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .bold()
                        .padding(.top)
                    Text(String(playerScore))
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .bold()
                        .padding()
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Reset") {
                        // start over the game
                        resetGame()
                    }
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                    .bold()
                    .background(.white)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0))
                    .font(.title2)
                    .padding()
                    Button("Quit the game") {
                        // move to ContentView view
                        backtoTitle = true
                    }
                    .frame(width: 190, height: 50)
                    .bold()
                    .background(.white)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0))
                    .font(.title2)
                    .padding(.bottom, 200)
                }
            }
            // enables the transition to another view
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isGameEnded) {
                ResultView(dataToPass: playerScore, arrayToPass: mistakenMoves)
                }
            // enables the transition to another view
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $backtoTitle) {
                ContentView()
                }
            // hide the back button at the top left corner 
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
        }
    }

    func resetGame() {
        idOfword = 0
        showTrueOrFalse = "Choose your answer!"
        playerScore = 0
        firstChoice = "午後"
        secondChoice = "午前"
        numberOfLeftWords = displayeWord.count
        usedMoves = []
    }
    
    func generateWordAndChoices() {
        // get the length of the array (.count)
        let lengthOfArray = displayeWord.count
        
        guard usedMoves.count < lengthOfArray else {
                print("All numbers have been used.")
                return
            }
        
        // randomise a number (the length of the array is the maximum) to generate a new word
        idOfword = Int.random(in: 1..<lengthOfArray)
        
        // check if the randomely generated number has been alreday used
        while usedMoves.contains(idOfword) {
            // generate a number again
            idOfword = Int.random(in: 1..<lengthOfArray)
        }

        // call a function to generate two choices
        let randomMeaning = getRandomMeaning()
        firstChoice = randomMeaning.firstChoice
        secondChoice = randomMeaning.secondChoice
    }

    func checkGameEnded() {
        // finish the game once all words in the array have been used
        if usedMoves.count == maxNumQuestion || numberOfLeftWords == 0 {
            // move to ResultView view
            isGameEnded = true
            
            let playerItem = PlayerItem(playerScore: playerScore, date: date)
            context.insert(playerItem)
        }
    }
    
    func checkAnswer(answer : String) {
        // add the chosen number to the list
        usedMoves.append(idOfword)
        
        // when the correct answer is chosen
        if answer == displayeWord[idOfword].meaning1
        {
            playerScore += 1
            showTrueOrFalse = "⭕️"
        }
        // when the incorrect answer is chosen
        else {
            showTrueOrFalse = "❌"
            mistakenMoves.append(idOfword)
            print("The words you got wrong\(mistakenMoves)")
        }
        
        // cause a bit of delay for displaying a new word and choices
        let interval: TimeInterval = 0.8
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + interval, execute: {
            // randomise a word 
            generateWordAndChoices()
            buttonClicked = false 
            numberOfLeftWords -= 1
            showTrueOrFalse = "Choose your answer!"
            // check if all words in the array have been used
            checkGameEnded()
        })
    }
    
    func getRandomMeaning() -> (firstChoice:String, secondChoice: String) {
        
        // randomise a number (0 or 1)
        let num = Int.random(in: 0...1)
        print(num)
        
        // assign choices based on the num variable
        if num == 0 {
            return (firstChoice: displayeWord[idOfword].meaning1, secondChoice: displayeWord[idOfword].meaning2)
        }
        else {
            return (firstChoice: displayeWord[idOfword].meaning2, secondChoice: displayeWord[idOfword].meaning1)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    PlayGameView()
}

}

View2 
struct ContentView: View {
      @Environment(\.modelContext) var context
      @Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\PlayerItem.playerScore, order:   .reverse),SortDescriptor(\PlayerItem.date, order: .reverse)]) var playerItems: [PlayerItem]

var body: some View {
                    // get the highest score 
                    Text("Your best score : \(playerItems.first?.playerScore ?? 0)")
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title2)
                        .offset(x:-10)
                        .padding(.bottom,40)
                    
                    // get the latest day when the game is play (this has an issue) 
                    if let firstItem = playerItems.first {
                        Text("\(firstItem.date)")
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            .bold()
                            .font(.title2)
                            .padding(.bottom,40)
                    } else {
                        Text("Let's study!")
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            .bold()
                            .font(.title2)
                            .padding(.bottom,40)
                    }
}
```

I have been following the tutorial on YouTube.

Comment: Assuming `firstItem.date` is of type `Date`, you could try
 using a `DateFormatter` to format the date exactly as you want.
 See: [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)
 
 There is also a `Text(firstItem.date, style: .date)` that you could use. It depends on what you want the `date` to look like.

Comment: @Iku, please show your `PlayerItem` code.

Comment: I don't know if SwiftData/CoreData is the best storage approach for this. You are going to keep creating new `PlayerItem` entities. If you want to keep a history for lots of different players then you can use SwiftData but you should ensure that you only create a single `PlayerItem` entity *per player* and just update the properties of that object. If you just want to store the last time anyone played the game, I would use `@AppStorage` (UserDefaults)

Comment: ＠soundflix, I just added the view! Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what error you get and what `(this has an issue)` mean.

Comment: @workingdog support Ukraine Silly me! Thanks!! 

Thread 1: Fatal error: failed to find a currently active container for PlayerItem happens to the following codes. 
Transient
private var _$backingData: any SwiftData.BackingData<PlayerItem> = PlayerItem.createBackingData()

Comment: Iku, sorry but I don't understand your question, `...struggling to display the day when the game is played`. Is you question about displaying a `Date`? Where exactly do you get the error?